# Ubuntu 18.04 "Super+O" can't trigger shortcut event

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I used xmodmap to changed left Alt as "Meta_L" and bind it solely to "mod4" (meaning I did remember to remove "Mod1" from Meta_L), the end result is left Alt behaves like "Command" in Mac OS so I can use the same keyboard shortcuts of IntelliJ and Sublime Text as I do in Mac OS.

However I found out that for whatever reason, "Super + O ('Oh' not '0')" or "Super + Shift + O" binding can't produce the shortcut event. At the same time "Super + B", "Super + Shift + up" and etc. all work as expected.

I was wondering if "Super + O" is system shortcut that override the application shortcut but after some research I can't find any.

At last, I used the same technique in Ubuntu 16.04 too and every thing works as expected.

Hope someone can share their experience and idea on this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this problem (Ubuntu 19.10) and found this page. I was trying to use Super+O for a shortcut but it didn't work. Thanks to Anbu's answer showing `gsettings` I was able to figure out what was grabbing the key:

```
(for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas); do gsettings list-recursively $schema; done) | grep '<Super>o'
```

It showed `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rotate-video-lock-static ['<Super>o']` so I removed it with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rotate-video-lock-static []
```

I restarted and was able to use the key again. I found *lots* more unwanted bindings with

```
(for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas); do gsettings list-recursively $schema; done) | grep '<Super>'
```

and then removed them with `gsettings set …`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, have mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did fresh install recently and was able to map Super+O without issues with xbindkeys.
Create a file ~/.xbindkeysrc with

```
"your command here"
 Mod2+Mod4 + o
```

And execute:

```
xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

However I had issue with Super+p which was resolved by disabling default key binding for switching monitors:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings switch-monitor=['']
```

That was a little tricky because "dconf dump" doesn't mention it while "gsettings list-recursively" does.

So, you may check your system keybinding and clean them up before using xbindkeys to change them.

Here are [dotfiles](https://github.com/Dmitra/dotfiles/blob/d5fef2481f9c964e84c2c7541c86a965ba636b75/system/gui/xbindkeysrc) where it works.

Answer (score -1):

I end up re-installing 16.04 LTS and everything works as expected.

Comment: Wow, that's disappointing. For me going back to 16.04 is not an option. I have the same problem and would love a solution working for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Good to know there is other people who uses the super key that way. I'll wait for some Ubuntu guru to append his solution and see if I can upvote that answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is so weird though, that I can register quite a lot combinations of Meta/Super + something except Meta/Super + O. What's up with that O? So curious!:D