# Disable orientation lock shortcut Super + O in ubuntu 18.04 gnome

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, pycharm

I'm having an issue where pycharm can't detect Super + O because it's being picked up by gnome for the orientation lock shortcut. I can disable orientation lock in dconf editor, but the shortcut seems to remain there. How might I get that shortcut back? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This question has been answered in https://askubuntu.com/a/1187318/1050087 .

That answer comes down to the following commands:

1. Find the gsetting for the rotation shortcut

   ```sh
   gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "<Super>"
   ```
2. Change or remove assigned keys:

   ```sh
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rotate-video-lock-static []
   ```
3. Reboot your computer

Comment: Log out is enough.