# Disable orientation and orientation shortcut Super+O

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome 3 and the key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> disables the auto screen rotation. I want to disable both automatic screen rotation and this particular keyboard shortcut.

I tried  the solutions in [Disable orientation lock shortcut Super + O in ubuntu 18.04 gnome](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236278/497398) and [Ubuntu 18.04 “Super+O” can't trigger shortcut event](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187318/497398) but they don't work. The shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> still shows me that screen orientation is toggled, even though the command `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "<Super>o"` returns nothing. These are my settings related to `rotat`-ion or `orient`-ation

```
> gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "\(orient\|rotat\)" 
org.gnome.eog.view autorotate false
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor ['XF86RotateWindows']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation priority 0
org.gnome.mousetweaks click-type-window-orientation 'vertical'
ca.desrt.dconf-editor.Settings saved-view '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/orientation/active'
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel lookup-table-orientation 1
com.ubuntu.touch.system orientation-lock 'none'
com.ubuntu.touch.system rotation-lock false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true
```

How do I disable screen orientation completely (along with shortcut)?